# libmodsecurity + owasp crs + nginx: regex for hyphen in name of a POST parameter in custom exclude rule

Tags: nginx, regex, mod-security, upload, rules

a paranoia_level = 3 of modsecurity forbids non-printable characters to be uploaded with POST payloads (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) in phase 2 using rule 920272 of owasp crs version 3.3.4

But, sometimes, it triggers for UTF-8 encoded passwords as well.

First attempt to deactivate rule 920272 works:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/login" \
    id:2001,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:RuleRemoveById=920272"
```

but it deactivates protection of ALL fields uploaded with POST.

Goal: deactivate 920272 for 2 POST parameters only:

- password
- hidden-password

Here things get complicated:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/login" \
    id:2001,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:RuleRemoveById=920272;ARGS:password"
```

works as well.

But a parameter "hidden-password" contains a hyphen.
It took several attempts to mask a hyphen with no success.

I have tried:

```
ctl:RuleRemoveById=920272;ARGS:hidden-password"
ctl:RuleRemoveById=920272;ARGS:hidden\-password"
ctl:RuleRemoveById=920272;ARGS:'hidden-password'"
ctl:RuleRemoveById=920272;ARGS:^/hidden-password/"
ctl:RuleRemoveById=920272;ARGS:^/hidden\-password/$"
```

and probably few more ...

Errors I get are either:

- `"Not a number: password"`
  or
- `"Expecting an action, got:  \-password"`
  or
- `"Expecting an action, got:  'hidden-password'"`

or somehow similar to one of above messages.

According to https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#user-content-ARGS
a parameter's name can be a regex.
Ok. Tried several ones (see above) and failed.

Do you know why ?